# Only load Vue component data once

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am loading data for components over AJAX within `beforeMount`. However, each time I collapse the `vue-strap` `accordion` element, it clears the entire contents forcing it to reload the AJAX every time. I tried wrapping the AJAX call in a condition that checks if the data was already filled before by doing `if (this.cycles.length === 0)`, but apparently it is also cleared upon accordion collapse.

Here is my parent template:

```
<template>
    <accordion :one-at-atime="true" type="info">
        <panel :is-open="index === 0" type="primary" :header="'Day ' + day.day" v-for="(day, index) in days" :key="day.id">
            <accordion :one-at-atime="true" type="success">
                <panel is-open type="success" header="Cycles">
                    <cycles
                            :day="day"
                    >
                    </cycles>
                </panel>
            </accordion>
        </panel>
    </accordion>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: [
            'plan'
        ],
        data() {
            return {
                days: []
            }
        },
        beforeMount: function () {
            var self = this;

            if (this.days.length === 0) {
                axios.get('/plans/' + this.plan.id + '/days/data')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        self.days = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is the `cycles.vue script that it loads repeatedly every time I collapse a`day` accordion containing it's cycles:

```
<template>
    <accordion :one-at-atime="true" type="info">
        <panel :is-open="index === 0" type="primary" :header="'Week ' + cycle.week + ': ' + cycle.name" v-for="(cycle, index) in cycles" :key="cycle.id">
            <form v-on:submit.prevent="update">
                ....misc input fields here...
            </form>
        </panel>
    </accordion>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: [
            'day'
        ],
        data() {
            return {
                cycles: []
            }
        },
        beforeMount: function () {
            var self = this;

            if (this.cycles.length === 0) {
                axios.get('/plans/days/' + this.day.id + '/cycles/data')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        self.cycles = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

How do I ensure the data doesn't get reloaded every time a simple show/hide happens on the accordion?

Comment: See [`<keep-alive>`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#keep-alive)

Comment: Good call, @RoyJ! It really could be it!

Comment: I tried `<keep-alive><cycles :day="day"></cycles></keep-alive>` but still reloads the cycle data every time I collapse the `day` accordion. I tried also wrapping the original loading point in my Blade template of the parent Vue template but still no good.

Answer (score 0):

Try [**adding `v-once`**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Cheap-Static-Components-with-v-once) to the `accordion`:

> #### Cheap Static Components with `v-once`
>
> Rendering plain HTML elements is very fast in Vue, but sometimes you
> might have a component that contains **a lot** of static content. In
> these cases, you can ensure that it's only evaluated once and then
> cached by adding the `v-once` directive to the root element, like
> this:
>
> ```
> Vue.component('terms-of-service', {
>   template: '\
>     <div v-once>\
>       <h1>Terms of Service</h1>\
>       ... a lot of static content ...\
>     </div>\
>   '
> })
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately, adding `v-once` to the accordion results in none of the content in any of the cycle accordions loading.

Comment: Can you try adding it to the  `panel` instead?

Comment: Another option is to move the call to `axios.get('/plans/days/' + this.day.id + '/cycles/data')` to the parent and pass the results to the `cycles` as props.

Comment: That's an option. I need to be able to dynamically add elements tho. Will passing elements as props cause problems with this?

Comment: You'd have to emit events and listen in the parent, the changes would have to be done in the parent.

Comment: Btw, have you used Vuex? If the parent thing seems too complicated, Vuex seems like the solution. If you haven't used it, though, you'd have to step aside and learn about it a bit.

Comment: Vuex would be new turf for me. I'll check into it tho. Thanks.